# Fragment BackStack doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-appcompat, back

**Overview**

Hi there, I'm currently trying to develop a android app with the new material design and compatipility back to API15. This time I would like to use only one activity and multiple fragments by replacing them in the activity.
While doing so, I've already run in multiple problems which i've either solved or just didn't reappeared... 
However, I still have a problem with the BackStack in the FragmentManager. It seems as the back button and the back icon in the toolbar (not actionbar!) are not working properly.
I have the feeling, that this problem is somehow caused due to the use of AppCompatActivity.
BTW: Since I find it very hard to understand whats the *right* way to code a api22 android app with *one Activity/ multiple Fragments*, every tip/critique from you guys is very welcome!

**Problem**

Back button and back icon in toolbar not working.

When I open the settings via the toolbar, neither the back button nor the back icon in the toolbar brings me back to the previous fragment. The back icon in the toolbar just doesn't do anything and the (software) back button closes the app

**Code**

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Load in first fragment
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, new MyListFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            // Replace current fragment with settings fragment
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

MyListFragment

```
Just a simple ListFragment
```

SettingsFragment

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Activate back icon in toolbar
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Inflate preferences
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

value/style.xml (same as value-v21/style.xml)

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="@color/primary">#2196F3</item>
        <item name="@color/primaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <item name="@color/accent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Update**

The (software) back button now works when overwriting onBackPressed() as following:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

**However, the back icon in the toolbar still doesn't take me back.**

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean when you say that back button is not working?

Comment: When I open the settings via the toolbar, neither the back button nor the back icon in the toolbar brings me back to the previous fragment. The back icon in the toolbar just doesn't do anything and the (software) back button closes the app.

Comment: you have to manually override the back button in optionItemsselected method

Comment: I've tried `if (id == R.id.home) { onBackPressed(); return true; }`. But it doesn't work

Comment: I think the back button in the toolbar only works if there is a parent activity assigned to the current activity. This is by default but I'm sure you can modify this behavior.

Comment: @GSala so does this mean that the toolbar back icon can only be used between two activities??

Comment: no, you can override onBackPressed, and put `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()` line there

Comment: @StupidBird That's the default behaviour, yes. But you can modify the behaviour through the onOptionsItemSelected like you commented.

Comment: @GSala **First question**: Could you please provide an example? I've managed to get the back button working by overriding onBackPressed as _Chaosit_ showed. But the back icon in the toolbar is still useless. **Second question**: If it is not intended to have a back icon in the toolbar when switching between fragments, why exists a PreferenceFragment? I mean, in every app, the settings screen has a back icon in the toolbar, right...?

Comment: @StupidBird First: `if (id == R.id.home) { onBackPressed(); return true; }` looked good to me. Maybe now that you have overridden onBackPressed() it works? Second: I think most people either wrap the PreferenceFragment inside a separate Activity or they change the up button behavior like you are trying. I'm sorry I cannot provide an example but take all I say as an idea of what might work, not as a statement.

Comment: @GSala Sadly the back icon in the toolbar still doesn't take me back to the first fragment. Is there any other workaround? Concerning your second answer I guess I'll stick to the PreferenceActivity with a PreferenceFragment in it. But sadly I'll still be in need to have another fragment, so the questions stays the same...

Comment: @StupidBird Ok, I looked around and instead of using `R.id.home` you should use `android.R.id.home`. Try and comment on results

Comment: @GSala Yes! Great, it works! Thank you very much. One last question (hopefully): How can I hide the back icon in the toolbar when the backstack is <= 1. I mean, is there any method in Activity like onFragmentReplace() or so?

Comment: For future questions, how to show the back icon depending on the backStack: Work with `getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener()`

Comment: Maybe you could do something like this:
`if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() <= 1){
        setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
}`  . Your solution looks more versatile though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the 'back' button in your `Toolbar`, is that it is not designed for back navigation. The backwards facing arrow in the `Toolbar` is for 'up' navigation (incredibly confusing at times -- and often shares the same behavior as the device 'back' button). See this link for further explanation:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

While there are certainly ways to override 'up' behavior, (e.g., overriding `android.R.id.home` in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method), it might make more sense to add a SettingsActivity that manages the SettingsFragment. You can then set the parent `Activity` of the SettingsActivity to the MainActivity in your manifest. Then both back and up should work the way you want without overriding any standard OS behavior:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`AppCompatActivity` uses `SupportFragmentManager` not `FragmentManager` so you should call `getSupportFragmentManager()` when starting a transition.

Note that for this to work properly your fragments also need to extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` from the support library for the back stack to work as expected.

It is then unnecessary to override the `onBackPressed()` method.